# Why is my code seg faulting when trying to extract the RGB components from a bmp file?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, bmp

I am trying to extract the RGB components from a bmp file but I am getting a seg fault when it gets to `Data[i][j].Blue`. I try printing out the hex of the three colors and it prints them out good but then it prints out that all RGB components are 0xFF and then it seg faults when it gets to the blue. Any help I get is greatly appreciated.

```
int inputColors(char *filename, struct INFOHEADER *InfoHeader, struct PIXEL **Data){
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    FILE *inputFile;

    printf("The height of the picture is %d\n", InfoHeader->Height);
    printf("The width of the picture is %d\n", InfoHeader->Width);

    if((inputFile = fopen(filename, "r")) == NULL){
            printf("Unable to open .bmp file\n");
            exit(1);
    }

    //Mallocing enough space for the 2D structures of pixels (colors)
    Data = (struct PIXEL **)malloc(InfoHeader->Width * sizeof(struct PIXEL *));
    for(i = 0; i < InfoHeader->Height; i++){
            Data[i] = (struct PIXEL *)malloc(InfoHeader->Height * InfoHeader->Width * sizeof(struct PIXEL));
    }

    //This goes until after we are down with the header
    fseek(inputFile, 54, SEEK_SET);

    //Inputing the data into the malloced struct
    i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < InfoHeader->Height; i++){
            for(j = 0; j < InfoHeader->Width; j++){
                    Data[i][j].Red = getc(inputFile);
            //      printf("The Red componet is %X\n", Data[i][j].Red);
                    Data[i][j].Green = getc(inputFile);
            //      printf("The green componet is %X\n", Data[i][j].Green);
                    Data[i][j].Blue = getc(inputFile);
            //      printf("The blue componet is %X\n", Data[i][j].Blue);
            }
    }

    fclose(inputFile);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: BMP is a binary format. The open mode should be `"rb"`.

Comment: Thanks to all! I figured out the problem. For future reference, both double loops should have width for the first loop and height for the second.

Comment: Your second `malloc` allocates way too much memory.You only need memory for 1 row/column here. And you don't need to cast the result.

Answer (score 1):

Well for starters, your first malloc uses

```
InfoHeader->Width * sizeof(struct PIXEL *)
```

But then you use InfoHeader->Height when iterating over the array.  Because of this mismatch, If InfoHeader->Width is smaller than InfoHeader->Height, it will not allocate enough memory to perform the iteration, and it will SEGFAULT.

Comment: So when I'm mallocing they both should be width?

Comment: @sarah No, when you allocate the outer array, you use height, and when you allocate the inner array, you use width.  At least, that is how your iterative loop logic is structured.

Comment: I tried that and it still seg faulted. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
Data = (struct PIXEL **)malloc(InfoHeader->Width * sizeof(struct PIXEL *));
//                                         ^^^^^
for(i = 0; i < InfoHeader->Height; i++){
//                         ^^^^^^
        Data[i] = (struct PIXEL *)malloc(InfoHeader->Height * InfoHeader->Width * sizeof(struct PIXEL));
}
```

Comment: Where height is should it be Width?